# OpenAI API error: "The model 'curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01' does not exist" when trying to delete a fine-tuned model

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Created a model from a jsonl file with prompts. I enter the command:

```
openai -k sk-blablablablablabla api fine_tunes.list
```

It shows information about this model:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "fine-tune",
      "id": "ft-yrlmcjagdwijfrnvkldsn",
      "hyperparams": {
        "n_epochs": 4,
        "batch_size": 1,
        "prompt_loss_weight": 0.01,
        "learning_rate_multiplier": 0.1
      },
      "organization_id": "org-kouf8eihlsamclsl",
      "model": "curie",
      "training_files": [
        {
          "object": "file",
          "id": "file-IyrkYUiefjwkq",
          "purpose": "fine-tune",
          "filename": "data_prepared.jsonl",
          "bytes": 417,
          "created_at": 1694757803,
          "status": "processed",
          "status_details": null
        }
      ],
      "validation_files": [],
      "result_files": [
        {
          "object": "file",
          "id": "file-jofepw8489hfidkdwfiw",
          "purpose": "fine-tune-results",
          "filename": "compiled_results.csv",
          "bytes": 742,
          "created_at": 1694757902,
          "status": "processed",
          "status_details": null
        }
      ],
      "created_at": 1694757804,
      "updated_at": 1694757903,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "fine_tuned_model": "curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01"
    }
  ],
  "next_starting_after": null
}
```

But I can't remove it.
I'm trying different things:

```
openai -k sk-blablablablablabla api models.delete -i <FINE_TUNED_MODEL>
openai -k sk-blablablablablabla api models.delete -i curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01
openai -k sk-blablablablablabla api models.delete -i ft-wyysqbYRFKo2p0ezNXa6F5sc
```

Tried it through Python code too:

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

def init_api():
    openai.api_key = os.getenv("AI_API_KEY")

init_api()

openai.Model.delete("curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01")
```

I got the following error:

```
The model 'curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01' does not exist (HTTP status code: 404)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error: The model 'curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01' does not exist (HTTP status code: 404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you got the following error: `The model 'curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01' does not exist`.

Meaning you have probably already successfully deleted your fine-tuned model. Consequently, it doesn't exist anymore when you try to delete it for the second, third, fourth, etc. time.

Use the [Models API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models) to [list all models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list). You shouldn't see `curie:ft-personal-2023-09-15-06-05-01`.

**Python:**

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

openai.Model.list()
```

**NodeJS:**

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI();

async function main() {
  const list = await openai.models.list();

  for await (const model of list) {
    console.log(model);
  }
}
main();
```